# How to Interpret Correlation of Fixed Effects in Longitudinal Mixed Effects model with Interaction

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, panel-data, multilevel-analysis

I have a longitudinal model with random slopes and a single time invariant predictor added as an interaction term. I am interested in how the growth of students scores differs based on how many minutes of lessons (LessonMinutes) they received.

I ran the model using lmer and the model and results are as follows:

```
model_interaction <- lmer(score ~ TimePoint*LessonMinutes + (TimePoint|StudentId), data=df)
summary(model_interaction)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: score ~ TimePoint * LessonMinutes + (TimePoint | StudentId)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 14033.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.2896 -0.6049 -0.0635  0.6084  3.3021 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 StudentId (Intercept) 0.23761  0.4874        
           TimePoint   0.02186  0.1479   -0.41
 Residual              0.36713  0.6059        
Number of obs: 6370, groups:  StudentId, 1699

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              1.378e-02  2.181e-02  2.587e+03   0.632    0.528    
TimePoint                8.600e-03  1.086e-02  1.368e+03   0.792    0.428    
LessonMinutes            1.297e-01  2.154e-02  4.926e+03   6.023 1.84e-09 ***
TimePoint:LessonMinutes -4.427e-02  6.557e-03  3.780e+03  -6.751 1.69e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TimPnt LssnMn
TimePoint   -0.743              
LessonMints  0.616 -0.573       
TmPnt:LssnM -0.314  0.090 -0.701
```

I'm quite surprised that the interaction term is significant and negative (i.e., more lessons results in a less steep growth trajectory). What I need help to better understand is how to interpret the correlation of fixed effects. They are all quite high and I get the sense that's important.

TimePoint ranges from 0 to 8 and the total number of TimePoints differs between students, ranging from a minimum of 3 to a max of 8.